# Spring JdbcTemplate and @Transactional not flushing

Tags: spring, transactions, jdbctemplate

I am using `JdbcTemplate` and a method with the `@Transactional` annotation to execute an update query. After the method executes no changes are persisted to the database. The `DataSource` for `JdbcTemplate` uses HikariCP and the `autoCommit` is set to `false` (can't change that unfortunately).

```
@Transactional
fun updateVersions() {
    jdbcTemplate.update("UPDATE ESLOCK SET MAX_CHANGELOG_EXECUTED = 1")
}
```

I wonder why does this statement not persist after it executes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up injecting the default `TransactionTemplate` in the app which allowed me to execute migrations manually:

```
class EsIndexer(
    private val jdbc: JdbcTemplate,
    private val tx: TransactionTemplate
) {
```

This way I could execute:

```
internal fun updateVersions() {
   tx.execute {
      jdbc.update("UPDATE MIGRATION_LOG SET MAX_MIGRATION_ID = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM MIGRATION)")
   }
}
```